# Regex to get string between \" and \"

Tags: c#, regex

As I am new to the regex, I would like to get help here.

> var test = "and ( [family]: \" trees \" or [family]: \" colors \" )"

I would like to extract the family lists:

> trees
>
> colors

I used the following pattern.

```
Regex.Matches(test, @"[family]:\*\");
```

It is not working for me, Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Matches(filters.queryString, @"\[family]:\s*""([^""]*)""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value.Trim())
    .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5bfamily%5d%3a%5cs*%22%28%5b%5e%22%5d*%29%22&i=and+%28+%5bfamily%5d%3a+%22+trees+%22+or+%5bfamily%5d%3a+%22+colors+%22+%29)

The values you need are in Group 1, and with `.Trim()`, the leading/trailing whitespace gets removed from those substrings.

**Pattern details**

- `\[family]:` - a `[family]` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"]*)` - Capturing group #1: zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a double quote.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/Db860h):

```
var test = "and ( [family]: \" trees \" or [family]: \" colors \" )";
var result = Regex.Matches(test, @"\[family]:\s*""([^""]*)""")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value.Trim())
        .ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s); // => trees, colors
```

Comment: Thanks @wiktor, It solved my problem also thanks for introducing about regex match tool

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a `[` literally,  you have to escape it `\[` or else it would start a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

One way to get the values you are looking for is to use a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(<=` and a positive lookahead `(?=`:

[`(?<=\[family]: ")[^"]+(?=")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5bfamily%5d%3a+%22%29%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%22%29&i=and+%28+%5bfamily%5d%3a+%22++trees++%22+or+%5bfamily%5d%3a+%22++colors++%22+%29)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\[family]: ")` Positive lookbehind that asserts that what is on the left side is `[family]:`
- `[^"]+` Match not a `"` one or more times using a negated character class
- `(?=")` Positive lookahead that asserts that what is on the right side is a `"`

For example:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\[family]: "")[^""]+(?="")";
var test = "and ( [family]: \" trees \" or [family]: \" colors \" )";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(test, pattern))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value.Trim());
```

That will result in:

```
trees
colors
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PIQQX71935)